# How do I expand only the argument of a function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I want to expand the argument of `Exp[ Sqrt[1+x]/x ]` in powers of x around x = 0.

```
Series[  Exp[ Sqrt[1+x]/x ] ,{x,0,3}]
```

does not work as there is an essential singularity.

The next best thing is to do

```
Exp[ Series[ Sqrt[1+x]/x ,{x,0,3}]  ]
```

But I want to do this outside the Exp function as there may be many such terms all added up...

Comment: You suggest this example is not entirely representative, so I don't know whether this will work in all your cases: `Exp[Sqrt[1 + x]/x] /. Exp[u_] :> Exp[Series[u, {x, 0, 3}]]`

Comment: Mr. Michael E2 , this will not do as I want to do this outside the argument of Exp function not inside but the effect has to be same as expanding the argument inside the argument of Exp.

Comment: Then I do not understand what output you want. Please update the question with the formula you want as the output for the expansion of `Exp[ Sqrt[1+x]/x ]`.

Comment: Imagine I want to expand the exponents of each of these terms (below) up to order x^3 . (x^2 + Cos[x]) Exp[Sqrt[1 + x]/x] +

Comment: What would be the **output** you would expect? In particular what are the terms up to order `x^3` of `Exp[Sqrt[1 + x]/x]` that you would expect to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the identity $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ to split the argment of [`Exp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exp) into a finite part and an infinite part. Here is some code to extract the finite and infinite parts of a series:

```
infinitePart[s:HoldPattern @ SeriesData[x_, x0_, __, inc_]] := Normal[
    s + SeriesData[x, x0, {}, 0, 0, inc]
]
finitePart[s_SeriesData] := s - infinitePart[s]
```

Now, making use of the identity:

```
ReplaceAll[
    Series[Exp[Sqrt[1+x]/x], {x, 0, 3}],
    Exp[s_SeriesData] :> Exp[infinitePart[s]] Exp[finitePart[s]
] //TeXForm
```

> $e^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(\sqrt{e}-\frac{\sqrt{e} x}{8}+\frac{9 \sqrt{e} x^2}{128}-\frac{145 \sqrt{e}
>    x^3}{3072}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)$

we obtain the form I think you're looking for.