# How to do this series expansion with Mathematica

Tags: series-expansion

Consider for large integers $n$ the expression $\sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{4 n^2+n}\right)$.

Since

$\sqrt{4 n^2+n}=2 n \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4 n}}$

we can use the standard series for the square root and next the standard series for $sin$ to find a series expansion of this expression around $\infty$. That is a simple first year exercise.

I was unable to do this computation in an elegant way with *Mathematica*. I expected the following to work:

```
Series[Sin[Sqrt[n+4 n^2] π], {n,∞,3}, Assumptions->{n ∈ Integers}]
```

$\sin \left(2 \pi  n+\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{\pi }{64 n}+\frac{\pi
   }{512 n^2}-\frac{5 \pi }{16384
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)\right)$

To my surprise, the expansion is only inside `Sin` and the fact that `n` is an integer is not used.

I tried to use `Normal` and `TrigExpand` without success. Finally I found a rather dirty trick to obtain the result I was looking for:

```
Series[Sin[Sqrt[n + 4 n^2] π], {n, ∞, 3}]  /.  Sin[x_] :> Sin[x - 2 π n]
```

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi }{64 \sqrt{2} n}+\frac{\frac{\pi
   }{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi ^2}{8192
   \sqrt{2}}}{n^2}+\frac{-\frac{5 \pi }{16384 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi
   ^2}{32768 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^3}{1572864
   \sqrt{2}}}{n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$

Can this result be found in a more straightforward way?

**Edit**

Let us reconsider

```
Series[Sin[Sqrt[n + 4 n^2] π], {n, ∞, 3}, Assumptions -> {n ∈ Integers}]
```

$\sin \left(2 \pi  n+\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{\pi }{64 n}+\frac{\pi
   }{512 n^2}-\frac{5 \pi }{16384
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)\right)$

Henric Schumacher is quite right in his assumption that we do not find a series expansion, but only a series expansion wrapped in `Sin`, because `Sin` has an essential singularity at `Infinity`. The documentation of `Series`, under `Possible Issues`, shows something similar. So this should not have surprised me.

The assumption that `n`is an integer has not prevented the appearance of the term `2πn` in the argument of `Sin`. Without that term, the result would immediately further evaluate to the result we are looking for. So we have to get rid of this term.

The argument of `Sin` is a `SeriesData` expression, which is atomic. Therefore, the substitution `2πn->0` does not work. But assignment is possible:

```
sd=Series[Sin[Sqrt[n+4 n^2] π],{n,∞,3}];
sd[[1,3,1]]=0;
sd
```

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi }{64 \sqrt{2} n}+\frac{\frac{\pi
   }{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi ^2}{8192
   \sqrt{2}}}{n^2}+\frac{-\frac{5 \pi }{16384 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi
   ^2}{32768 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^3}{1572864
   \sqrt{2}}}{n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$

Another way of getting rid of the term `2πn` is to use `Normal` and `FullSimplify` with the assumption that `n` is an integer, as done in the answer of Mikado. After that, we need another call of `Series` to arrive at the desired result.

To summarize: at the moment, it seems that there is no straightforward way for finding this series expansion by *Mathematica*, while it is easily found with pen and paper.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that there are infinitely many summands in the Laurant series expansion of `Sin` at `Infinity`? Exactly as `Exp`, `Sin` has an essential singularity at `Infinity`. Things like `SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, Infinity, -5}]` work fine.

Comment: @Henrik: please see the edit.

Comment: Could use `Series` twice, with `Normal` and `Refine` in the middle to handle the `n` integrality. `In[2]:= Series[
 Refine[Normal[
   Series[Sin[Sqrt[n + 4 n^2] \[Pi]], {n, \[Infinity], 3}]], 
  Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers}], {n, \[Infinity], 3}]

Out[2]= SeriesData[n, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {
 2^Rational[-1, 2], Rational[-1, 64] 2^Rational[-1, 2] Pi, 
  Rational[1, 512] 2^Rational[-1, 2] Pi + Rational[-1, 8192]
     2^Rational[-1, 2] Pi^2, 
  Rational[1, 
    3145728] ((-480)
      2^Rational[1, 2] Pi + 48 2^Rational[1, 2] Pi^2 + 2^Rational[
      1, 2] Pi^3)}, 0, 4, 1]`

Comment: Oops, I missed the substantially similar response by @Mikado. (I thought I had made the same comment yesterday but I guess I never submitted it.)

Answer (score 6):

The following gives the same result, but with less explicit fiddling

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers, 
 Series[FullSimplify[Normal[Series[
     Sin[Sqrt[n + 4 n^2] π], {n, ∞,3}]]], {n, ∞, 3}]]
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I tried Simplify, but that did not work. See also the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208905/45431) to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146476/45431), we can split the argument of [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin) into a finite part and an infinite part and then use the identity: $$\sin (x+y)=\sin (x) \cos (y)+\cos (x) \sin (y)$$

Here is some code to obtain the finite and infinite parts of a series.

```
infinitePart[s:HoldPattern @ SeriesData[x_, x0_, _, _, _, inc_]] := Normal[
    s + SeriesData[x, x0, {}, 0, 0, inc]
]
finitePart[s_SeriesData] := s - infinitePart[s]
```

Making use of the identity:

```
s = ReplaceAll[
    Series[Sin[Sqrt[n + 4 n^2] π], {n, ∞, 3}],
    Sin[s_SeriesData] :> With[{i = infinitePart[s], f = finitePart[s]},
        Sin[i] Cos[f] + Cos[i] Sin[f]
    ]
];
s //TeXForm
```

> $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi }{64 \sqrt{2} n}+\frac{-\frac{\pi }{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi ^2}{8192
>    \sqrt{2}}}{n^2}+\frac{\frac{5 \pi }{16384 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{32768 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi ^3}{1572864
>    \sqrt{2}}}{n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)\right) \sin (2 \pi  n)+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi
>    }{64 \sqrt{2} n}+\frac{\frac{\pi }{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi ^2}{8192 \sqrt{2}}}{n^2}+\frac{-\frac{5 \pi }{16384
>    \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{32768 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi ^3}{1572864
>    \sqrt{2}}}{n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)\right) \cos (2 \pi  n)$

Now, we can simplify the series assuming that `n` is an integer:

```
Simplify[s, n ∈ Integers] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi }{64 \sqrt{2} n}-\frac{(\pi -16) \pi }{8192 \sqrt{2} n^2}+\frac{\pi  \left(-480+48 \pi
>    +\pi ^2\right)}{1572864 \sqrt{2} n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$